# Why text is not smooth in Chrome?

Tags: easeljs, createjs

As I am rendering text on canvas, I noticed that the resulted text in IE9 is smooth and anti-aliased, but the same experiment at Chrome, the text is jagie and not smooth ..

Can some one please explain?

I tried to check documentation at http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/modules/EaselJS.html but, I couldn't find any property that is related to anti-alias of text ..

Comment: There are a lot of not quite answered questions and opinions about this. It's not EaselJs though, it's the canvas element. If you search for "chrome font anti alias canvas" or font smoothing, you'll see the issues people are having and the success and failures of various attempts. Chrome on Windows often renders downloaded fonts very poorly compared to IE9+.

Comment: Did you see this post http://joubert.posterous.com/crisp-html-5-canvas-text-on-mobile-phones-and ? would it help?